# Always have \blacksquare box appear to right of page

Tags: formatting

In this MWE, I wanted to always have the `\blacksquare` box appear to the right of the page and one line below the last line of text.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{52,177,201}

\newcommand{\newqed}{{\hfill\color{ocre}\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Problems from Chapter 2}

\section{Problem 2.4}\index{Problem 2.4}

\subsection{Problem 2.4}
Line 1: This is just some test text. This is just some test text. This is.
\newqed

\subsection{Solution 2.4}\index{Solution 2.4}

Line 2: This is just some test text. This is just some test text. This is just.
\newqed

\end{document}
```

Comment: Really one line below? When the last line is short you get a very large white space and the square would appear as hanging from nothing. And the accepted answer doesn't place the square one line below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `amsthm` package already provides the infrastructure:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{52,177,201}

\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\textcolor{ocre}{$\blacksquare$}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Problems from Chapter 2}

\section{Problem 2.4}\index{Problem 2.4}

\subsection{Problem 2.4}
Line 1: This is just some test text. This is just some test text. This is.\qed

\subsection{Solution 2.4}\index{Solution 2.4}

Line 2: This is just some test text. This is just some test text. This is just.\qed

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You must add `\null` before `\hfill` because `\hfill` is removable item. Your paragraph ends by

```
...text.<space>\hfill<square>\parfillskip\par
```

If the paragraph is broken in the space then following removable items (i.e. `\hfill`) are removed and there is next line with `<square>\parfillskip` which puts `square` to the left. But if `\null` (i.e. empty box) is before `\hfill` then the next line is in the form `\null\hfill<square>\parfillskip` and this puts the `<square>` to the right because `\parfillskip` is only `0pt plus 1fil` by default.

Your macro looks like:

```
\def\newqed{{\null\nobreak\hfill\color{ocre}\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}}
```